# Ajax call to protected (authorize) controller method (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

An ASP.NET Core MVC application is using cookie authentication. I would like to execute an ajax call which is calling a protected (authorize) post method. It is somehow possible to pass the token/ authentication cookie from the ajax to the controller? Currently, the post method is not called.

e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public string DoSomething()
{
    return "DoSomething"
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnDoSomething').click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/DoSomething",
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
     </script>
}
```

Comment: So you will need add cookie to ajax call header.

Comment: @QiangFu Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Did you search SO?  Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916829/jquery-ajax-cookie) help?

Comment: @freedomn-m I've definitely searched on SO, but some provided solutions are outdated or solve another issue. The application is using aspnetcore [cookie authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-cookie-authentication), but what is the correct way to call a protected controller method (OP DoSomething method) while using a ajax call? Some posts say the cookie should be passed automatically, but when the ajax call is performed the result is a 401.